# How to change favicon.ico and page title (Vue + Webpack)?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have created my project with vue-cli, running 'vue init webpack project-name'. I cannot figure out how to change the page title and the favicon displayed.

Somehow the page title is always 'Vue App' and favicon is the Vue logo. How do I change these? They seems to be generated from somewhere in the webpack config, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: Look into `public/index.html`

Comment: Ah, per [Project Structure](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/structure.html),  `index.html` should be in the root folder

Comment: I've tried to change the title inside index.html to <title>My App Name</title>, but this is not being used. Somewhere in the configs 'Vue App' title is generated.

Comment: Change title and restart dev server

Comment: I changed the title in index.html and ran 'npm run build' to locally run the server. Still shows the 'Vue App' title

Comment: @OskarGusgård `npm run build` does _not_ run the server locally. Perhaps, you have `npm run dev` instance running somewhere. Changing `<title>` in `index.html` should work without dev server restart though.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant 'npm run dev'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a public folder to the project root. Then I moved my index.html and favicon into the public folder.

```
//This is in the index.html head
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vue-cli, this is the only way I could find to get the page title to not unprofessionaly flash "Vue App" on load.  If someone finds an easier solution, please share!

Create **custom-index.html** with your own title, then in **vue.config.js**:

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
...
plugins: [
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      showErrors: true,
      cache: true,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/custom-index.html'),
  })
],
```